# Read/Write to File with Custom Properties Syntax using Java Properties Class?

Tags: java, regex, firefox, text, properties

I'm able to read/write to file with standard `key=value` syntax using `java.Util.Properties` class with the following code:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

properties.setProperty(key, value);
```

However, I'd like to read/edit the `user.js` file of `Firefox` profile which contains custom properties syntax:

```
PREFIX     KEY                        VALUE
user_pref("browser.tabs.warnOnClose", true);
user_pref("browser.tabs.warnOnCloseOtherTabs", true);
user_pref("browser.laterrun.bookkeeping.profileCreationTime", 1638899590);
user_pref("browser.laterrun.bookkeeping.sessionCount", 3);
user_pref("dom.push.userAgentID", "dd6709b4XXXXXX517f7bf9e78");
```

Notice how each property contains some standard **prefix** (i.e, *user_pref("*), a **key** (i.e, *browser.tabs.warnOnClose*) and a **value** (i.e, *true*, *1638899590*, *"dd6709b4XXXXXX517f7bf9e78"*).

I guess this can be achieved with `RegEx` but I'd prefer to solve this in a simpler way if possible.

Is it possible to achieve this directly with the `Java Properties` class or must I use `RegEx`?

Thanks

Comment: That’s a JavaScript file.  You need a JavaScript engine to parse it properly.  Using regex will work in some cases but will eventually fail.

Comment: @VGR It can't be parsed with plain Java?

Comment: Not with any existing class.  You can certainly write your own parser in Java, but a regular expression won’t be enough.  Consider this:  what if a string value contains a double-quote character?

Comment: @VGR I don't think double-quote characters are acceptable values in `prefs.js` or `user.js` but could potentially be an issue when writing a more generalized parser..

Comment: My prefs.js has this line in it: `user_pref("browser.newtabpage.pinned", "[{\"url\":\"https://amazon.com\",\"label\":\"@amazon\",\"searchTopSite\":true}]");`